# Sendgrid email validation response fields

Tags: sendgrid

I am working on some integration and uses sendgrid email validation as part of it. The issue i am facing is the sendgrid API send 'RISKY' response to some valid email addresses. I looked into their documentation but there is not much on what bases they identify the email addresses as Invalid or Risky. Can some one help please.

Looked in the sendgrid API documentation but there is not much there to detail how they grade the email addresses.

Comment: Why the MuleSoft tag? The question is about sendgrid, whatever that is. This doesn't seem to be an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stackoverflow. programming question for this site. Specifically "Questions asking for customer support with third-party services (such as App Stores) are off-topic".

Comment: I am working on a mulesoft integration that is why choose the mulesoft tag. I don't think this is off-topic.

Comment: Would you change any part of the question if you were working on a Java or Python application?

Comment: I am not sure what the question exactly is. But I just want to note that I was looking a solution for a problem that I couldn't figure out with the resources I found. As I am a new to this site I was not sure if a choose the right tag or not. So if is wrong to ask none coding question here I apologize.

Comment: Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying  questions. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).